# Как добавить такую карту яндекса?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-jsapi

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как добавить такую карту яндекса? Что за карта вообще?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/ тут смотрел? поидее там есть всё, что предлагает официально Яндекс